# Find cluster boundary in given matrix

Tags: matrix, data-structures

Given matrix contains many clusters.  Cluster is represented by 1's.

For Example:

0 1 1 1 0

1 1 1 0 0

0 0 0 1 1

1 1 0 0 1

In this example, there are 3 clusters (connected 1's horizontally or vertically).

Now suppose that matrix size is very big and it contains too many clusters.

Now my question is, I want to know the boundary of all the clusters.

For example given matrix:

0 0 1 1 0

0 1 1 1 1

0 0 1 1 0

0 0 0 1 0

Now output should be coordinates of bold locations:

0 0 **1** **1** 0

0 **1** 1 1 **1**

0 0 **1** **1** 0

0 0 0 **1** 0

Consider matrix is huge with many such clusters, suggest optimized way of finding boundaries of all clusters.

Answer (score 0):

A 1 is on the boundary of some cluster only when it has an 0 as one of its immediate neighbors or when it's on the outline of the matrix, so the naive method would be outputting the coordinates of 1's on the outline, then going through all the other matrix cells and outputting the coordinates of 1's satisfying the said condition.

It doesn't look like there is a way to optimize this algorithm, though.

Suppose we have a huge matrix with only one random 1 inside it. There is no way to find it without going through each and every cell out there.

There is also no way to skip 1's of the same cluster by following the outline of it.
Consider this example:

0 0 0 **1 1 1 1 1 1 1**
0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 **1**
0 **1 1 1 1 1** 0 **1** 0 **1**
0 0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 **1**
0 0 0 0 0 **1 1 1 1 1**

One cluster can easily fit inside another one, so following the outline is not an option.